# How to get fieldname from SQL Server DB using the field ID

Tags: c#, html, css, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my views, I have a few drop-down lists that I use to get the ID and show the value to the user so they know what they are choosing. But in the view that I use to list everything that has already been added, it shows the chosen ID, but I want the name to appear

I tried this but it always shows the status that has the ID 1, which is the status "Active"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.status,
                    (SelectList)ViewBag.listStatus,
                    new { @class disabled = "" })
```

//controller

```
    {
        public ActionResult listStatus()
        {
            var list= ListsDAO.listStatus();
            return View(list);
        }
    }
```

//DAO

```
{
    public static IEnumerable<LISTS> listStatus()
    {
        using (var ctx = new PadraoEntities())
        {
            var result= from lists in ctx.LISTS
                            where lists.TYPE_LIST== "STATUS"
                            select new
                            {
                                lists.IDE_LIST,
                                lists.DES_LIST,
                                lists.VLR_LIST
                            };
            var list= new List<LISTS>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                list.Add(new LISTS()
                {
                    IDE_LIST = item.IDE_LIST,
                    VLR_LIST = item.VLR_LIST,
                    DES_LIST = item.DES_LIST
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

//view add

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control -Label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.status(SelectList)ViewBag.listStatus, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

//view list

```
 {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.ststus,(SelectList)ViewBag.listStatus,new { disabled = "" })
    }
```

when listing id 1, I expected "active" to appear, id 2 shows "inactive", etc

Comment: Where the values active , inactive etc are stored?

Comment: we have a table in the database which has the fields IDE_LIST(id), VLR_LISTS(value) and DES_LIST(additional information)

Answer (score 1):

Try this //controller

```
public ActionResult listStatus()
    {
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(//Code to get id and its property, "StatusId", "Status");
        var list= ListsDAO.listStatus();
        return View(list);
    }
```

//View

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, "TaskId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Status", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping

My add view is working fine now, but I still need help with the view that lists the records in the table.

In my case, that view shows only the first record, I need to pass a parameter such as the ID to the controller so that it shows the record with the selected ID.

I will be very grateful if you can help me with this

Comment: Create a method which will get Status Id along with its status and call that method where you want to get it.